# Access WAMP Alias directory with PHP

Tags: php, directory, wamp, alias, glob

First time using Stack, sorry if I am doing something wrong!

I have a WAMP server on my home machine. I created Alias directories pointing to directories outside my server root. They are working fine and are accessible from my site and behave like child directories.

But when I try to use php to access these directories (such as to use glob to list only specific filetypes from inside these alias directories) php functions don't recognize them as directories inside the root so I can't figure out what path to give to the php functions.

Any suggestions on how to use php with directories outside of the server root? Maybe Alias directories are not the way to go?

Comment: You can either use symbolic links in the file system instead of aliases and allow php and the http server to follow those, or you need a catalog of folder mappings in your php preamble. But a general hint: it usually us not a good idea to publish assets (files, documents and stuff) directly via the http server, bt to route requests to those through a validating and authorizing script. So maybe you do not need those aliases at all?

Comment: Show your Alias definition so we can see what you missed.

Comment: I actually found a work around. PHP functions work fine if they are in a index.php file inside the alias directory. Its just I cant use those functions from inside the root directory.